# Why is QHBoxLayout causing widgets to overlap?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to place several instances of a custom `QPushButton` subclass adjacent to one another. For some reason, the buttons overlap one another when painted. A simplified example of the problem is below.

Here is the (incorrect) output:

[image: overlapping]

Here is the code:

```
#include <QtGui>

class MyButton : public QPushButton {
public:
  explicit MyButton(Qt::GlobalColor color, QWidget *parent = NULL)
    : QPushButton(parent), color_(color) {
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
  }
  QSize sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(50, 25);
  }
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setOpacity(0.5);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, width(), height(), color_);
  }
private:
  Qt::GlobalColor color_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget widget;
  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  layout->setSpacing(0);
  MyButton *w1 = new MyButton(Qt::red);
  MyButton *w2 = new MyButton(Qt::green);
  MyButton *w3 = new MyButton(Qt::blue);
  layout->addWidget(w1);
  layout->addWidget(w2);
  layout->addWidget(w3);
  widget.setLayout(layout);
  widget.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

What is causing this, and how do I fix it? BTW, I tried something similar with regular `QWidget` subclasses (instead of `QPushButton` subclasses), and there is no problem. It is something peculiar to `QPushButton`.

**UPDATE:** I'm really thinking now that this is a bug. I submitted it to the [Qt Bug Tracker](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-14591); we'll see what the Trolls think. In any case, deriving from `QAbstractButton` fixes the drawing problem ... I just had to re-implement some of the functionality I needed.

**UPDATE 2:** The Trolls at Qt provided a solution (workaround?); I posted their fix as an answer below. I'm leaving it up to their team to determine if this is a feature or bug. It apparently only behaves differently on the Mac.

Comment: I don't see anything that fixes the size of your pushbutton. You specify that it will be fixed and the sizeHint, but not he actual size. Do you do it in your real code or not?

Comment: @Live: But isn't that the point of the QHBoxLayout? Is it not supposed to use the size hints to determine the ideal size for each widget? (Allowing some to expand / contract if the size hint and policy allow, for example.)

Comment: @Live: I verified that the sizes are OK. If you do a qDebug() << size(), it is correct.

Comment: What does it do if you stretch your window (can you?)

Comment: @Live: if you stretch the window, the margins between the buttons expand and the buttons stay the fixed size. If you do a layout->addStretch(1), then the buttons remain overlapping. It is almost as if the layout is incorrectly calculating the size needed for all the buttons. I may submit this as a bug.

Comment: I had a chance to test your code this evening. It compiles and runs correctly on Windows 7 with Qt 4.6.2 and on Linux with Qt 4.5.3. so I've deleted my previous answer. So it may be a bug under MacOS. Can you indicate the version of OS and Qt?

Comment: @Arnold: I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.4; Qt 4.7.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to add the following to the subclass:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect);
```

Apparently it is only necessary on the Mac platform; Windows and Linux display the layout as expected.

Comment: @chacham15: You can add it to the constructor of the subclass, the `MyButton` in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling setSizePolicy() and reimplement sizeHint(), I would try to simply call

`setFixedSize(50, 25)`

in your constructor. This should update the sizeHint on its own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `setFixedSize` causes the same behavior. I'm really starting to think this is just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I have tested it. What version you use? I use Qt 4.6.3 and it is fine.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.4; Qt 4.7.0

Comment: I think that is the problem. Yes may be it is a bug.