# How to remove margins of QLayout completely (Mac OS specific)

Tags: macos, qt

Let me explain a simplified situation. In Qt Creator, create a `QHBoxLayout` containing a `QPushButton` and another `QHBoxLayout` which contains a second `QPushButton` (i.e. nested layout). As demonstrated below:
[image: Nested layout]

Both `QHBoxLayout`s have 0 values for the four margins (left, top, right, bottom). I would expect the borders of the layouts (red rectangles in the attached image) are perfectly on the borders of the two buttons, and the two buttons are perfectly aligned vertically. However it's clearly not the case as can been seen in the image. The second button is a bit higher than the first one. As a matter of fact, setting the bottom margin between 0 and 8 has no visual difference, the bottom margin only grows from 9 pixels, at least on Mac OS.

Any explanation of this behaviour? And how to remove the margins completely instead of calling `layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`?

I am aware of `QStyle::PM_LayoutBottomMargin` etc. in `QStyle::PixelMetric`, which is supposed to be the default bottom margin on a specific platform. But why these values wouldn't be overwritten by `layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`?

EDIT:  I just tried the same on Windows, indeed everything is as expected (without margins). So this question is only reproducible on Mac OS.

Comment: Are you referring to the proper method in Qt Designer, or in code? `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` is appropriate for code, otherwise, use the properties window in Qt Creator for the appropriate layout to set margins to 0.

Comment: I do not see this problem when I construct the same thing. In fact, my default content margins were already zero. Can you post the .ui file?

Comment: @owacoder, actually I was referring both. I found this issue in my code by setting `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`, and later tried in Qt Designer which gave the same result after setting the margins properties to 0.

Comment: @goug Are you working on Mac OS as well? There might be platform difference for this particular case. From what I've tried on my Mac, the bottom margin is always at least 8 pixels even after setting it to zero, either by code or in Qt Designer. I'm not allowed to upload files, but the .ui is just as simple as described in the question. BTW, margins with 0 value are indeed the default, but apparently the 0 value has no effect as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm on Windows. I don't have a development environment set up on my Mac at home. I see that someone has posted a bug report and a workaround, so hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is only visible for several certain widgets (e.g `QPushButton`, `QComboBox` etc) on Mac OS.

Setting `Qt::WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect`attribute on those widgets would solve it:

```
button->setAttribute(Qt::WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect);
```

Reference: [QMacStyle: QPushButtons always have space below when in a QLayout](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2699)

A related issue with the same solution could be found here: [Why is QHBoxLayout causing widgets to overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978889/why-is-qhboxlayout-causing-widgets-to-overlap)