# PyQt5: How do you align widgets on different hierarchy levels?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, widget, alignment

I'm trying to align the sides of a top button and a bottom button on different hierarchy levels in the widget tree. The top button is on the same level as a widget with horizontal box layout that contains the bottom button.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
    self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0) # this is the main window

    central_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    central_widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
    main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    button = QPushButton("1")
    main_layout.addWidget(button)
    button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    widget = QWidget()
    main_layout.addWidget(widget)
    widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    button = QPushButton("2")
    layout.addWidget(button)
    button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    button = QPushButton("3")
    layout.addWidget(button)
    button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
```

I've called setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0) on every object involved, widgets and layouts.

Yet I'm getting this result:

[image]

As you can see, the left side of button 2 isn't aligned with the left side of button 1, and the same goes for the other side.

I want them aligned (and since the actual code is more complicated than this, I'd like to stay with this structure of different hierarchy levels).

I'd appreciate your help with this, thanks!

---

Edit: here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(120, 50)

        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        button = QPushButton("1")
        main_layout.addWidget(button)
        button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        widget = QWidget()
        main_layout.addWidget(widget)
        widget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        button = QPushButton("2")
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        button = QPushButton("3")
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: That should not happen. Can you please provide a valid and complete [mre] and also include more details about versions of your OS, PyQt *and* Qt?

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I've added an example as an edit to the original post.
Versions:
macOS Ventura 13.4.1,
PyQt5 5.15.9,
Qt 5.15.10

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux, so I believe this might be a macOS related "issue". Can you try to add `app.setStyle('fusion')` right after the creation of the `app` instance and see if the issue persists? In either ways, also try to call `button.setAttribute(Qt.WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect)` for all buttons 
*and* the container widget. This may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466352). Also, try to directly add the layout instead of a further widget: remove that `widget` and just do `main_layout.addLayout(layout)`.

Comment: You could also use a gridlayout.

Comment: @musicamante , thanks a lot for your input and references! The `button.setAttribute(Qt.WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect)` workaround works for me. @mahkitah , I was reluctant to switch to a grid layout, but I'm now considering it again. Thanks for this suggestion! [off topic edit: those mentions don't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?]